# Python function like SAGA Grid Gridding?

Tags: interpolation, saga, geopandas, geodataframe

For a python script, I'm searching for a function that does the same as SAGA Grid gridding, an exponential interpolation on GeoPandas GeoDataFrame.

Does anyone know one?